# Angular MatDatepicker - How to make "from-to" validation between two datepickers?

Tags: angular, mat-datepicker

I have two fields which are datepickers. The first represents the FROM date period and the second represents the TO date period. I use Angular MatDatepickers for this. How can I validate that the user cannot select a FROM date greater than TO date?

```
 <div class="row no-gutters">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="date-input">
                  <input class="datepicker form-control form-control-sm form-control-portal"
                         matInput
                         [matDatepicker]="creationDateFromPicker"
                         placeholder="from"
                         (click)="creationDateFromPicker.open()"
                         formControlName="createdDateFrom">
                  <mat-datepicker #creationDateFromPicker></mat-datepicker>
                </div>
              </div>
              <p class="ml-1 mr-1 mt-1">-</p>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="date-input">
                  <input class="datepicker form-control form-control-sm form-control-portal"
                         matInput
                         [matDatepicker]="creationDateToPicker"
                         placeholder="to"
                         (click)="creationDateToPicker.open()"
                         formControlName="createdDateTo">
                  <mat-datepicker #creationDateToPicker></mat-datepicker>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: After select first date in the method set min date for second calendar with selected date from first calendar

Comment: @Pawlit, why not use a mat-date-range selector? this last version of material has this option:https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#date-range-selection. The other option is declare in the second matDatePicker `[min]="form.get('createdDateFrom').value"`